# Library for .Net (4.8) for LDAPS (LDAP-SSL) for easy search with PrincipalSearcher and GroupPrincipal

Tags: .net, ssl, nuget, ldap

We have to switch to LDAPS (LDAP with SSL).
I now need a library or third party dll to use PrincipalContext , GroupPrincipal and PrincipalSearcher.
The problem is: with LDAPS you don't have a PrincipalContext, which is our startpoint for searching, but a LdapConnection.
Anyone who has any idea how to solve this instead of rewriting and testing the whole class we have made for LDAP based on PrincipalContext , GroupPrincipal and PrincipalSearcher?

Current code example for LDAP:

```
           using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Domain))
           {
               using (GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx))
               {
                   using (PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup))
                   {
                       Logger.Log("searching all groups", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, Logger.LogLevel.Info);
                       foreach (Principal found in srch.FindAll())
                       {
                           if (found is GroupPrincipal)
                           {
                               GroupPrincipal group = found as GroupPrincipal;
                               if (group.Guid.HasValue)
                               {
                                   if (!groups.Any(x => x.Group.Guid == group.Guid.Value))
                                   {
                                       AddGroupsRecursiv(group, ref groups);
                                   }
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
```

I tried so search for some NuGet - packages, which are not to old, but none provide the usage of
PrincipalContext , GroupPrincipal and PrincipalSearcher.